# Read XMLDocument node without reading its child nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml

**Sample XML**

```
<A>
   <B>
      <B1/>

      <B2/>
      <B3/>
      <B4/>
      <B5/>
   </B>
   <C>
      <C1/>
      <C2/>
      <C3/>
      <C4/>
      <C5/>
   </C>
</A>
```

**Query:**
C#
When I read the the child nodes of A it retuns nodes B & C with their child nodes.

Is there any possibility so that I can get only B & C without their respective child nodes

I need to populate the tree with this type of xml & the xml file is quite big. so I need to load the childs at the time of expanding any node

**Requirement is**
Suppose I try to expand A node the I want only B & C,

If I expand B then I want B1 to B5

Comment: What are you using to parse and query the document? You need to be more specific. It would also help to post the relevant part of the XML you are trying to query.

Comment: Sample XML is 
<A>
   <B>
      <B1/>
      <B2/>
      <B3/>
      <B4/>
      <B5/>
   </B>
   <C>
      <C1/>
      <C2/>
      <C3/>
      <C4/>
      <C5/>
   </C>
</A>

Comment: Which language? JS? XSLT/XPath? XQuery?

Comment: using Selectnodes of XMLDocument to get the desired nodes

Comment: Also, you need to explain *what's wrong* with B and C having their child nodes. Depending on what you do you could simply ignore them if you don't need them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'expand node'? What are you using to load and read the XML? If you are using an XmlDocument then all the processing is done when you first load the XML (as far as I know) so there is no cost in accessing child nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Use a XmlReader. XmlDocument by design has to load the whole Xml document into memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you use java, you can implement a [SAX Handler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) building your DOM and ignoring the children.

Comment: FYI he changed the question a lot. THis was correct answer for the first version of question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a badly worded question so I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but if you just want all the child nodes of the root (A) then use an XmlDocument with XPath like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFile);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/A/*");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes){
   //DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that still loads the entire XML document into memory.  See foreachdev's answer.

Comment: Yes, I almost mentioned XmlReader but the question was not worded very well so it was rather difficult to know what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question right, u need to get children of the node without getting their children. this can be done by xquery
(child::*)

so if u apply it in A node it will give B and C. if u apply it in B then it will give B1-B5.